# Null convolution

Tags: convolution

The convolution of two functions $u(t),v(t)$ is defined as
$$u(t)*v(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} u(\tau)\,v(t-\tau)\,d\tau.$$

Could you provide a simple example of two functions $u(t),v(t)$ for which their convolution is null for all $t$, without $u(t)$ or $v(t)$ being null for all $t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementing Alex Ortis answer. I agree that using the property that the Fourier Transform $\mathcal{F}$ is such that $\mathcal{F}\{u * v\} = \mathcal{F}\{u\} \mathcal{F}\{v\}$ is the most straightforward way to come up with an example.

For a concrete example of $u$ and $v$ for which $\mathcal{F}\{u\} \mathcal{F}\{v\} = 0$ you can use the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function). The Fourier transform of a sinc is a [rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function). For instance, $u(t) = \text{sinc}(\omega_1 t)$ and $v(t) = \text{sinc}(\omega_1 t) \sin(\omega_2 t)$ for appropriate choice of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ should give you the example. Since their Fourier transform can be different then zero in intervals that do not overlap.

To show that, use (besides the Fourier properties mentioned above) the [translation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Translation_/_time_shifting) and write $\sin(\omega_2 t) = \frac{\exp(j\omega_2 t) - \exp(-j\omega_2 t)}{2 j}$.

Comment: I included a link in the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function

Comment: that's a link to the **_sinc_** function. I've never heard of the "sync" function...

Comment: $sinc(x) = sin(x) / x$ when $x \not=0$ and is equal to one when $x=0$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working out the example provided

Comment: no, that site, and everyone else, says $sinc(x)=\sin(x)/x$.

Comment: it was a typo... fixed

Comment: the transforms of $sinc(\omega_1t)$ and $sinc(\omega_2t)$ do not have disjoint support

Comment: I sugested  $u(t)=sinc(\omega_1 t)$  and $v(t)=sinc(\omega_1 t)sin(\omega_2 t) $

Comment: you can use the translation property to show the disjoint support. By multiplying by $sin(\omega x)$ you dislocate the Fourier transform... So you can have disjoint suport

Comment: sorry, I missed your $v$. Probably because I would have said just $u=sinc$, $v(t)=e^{it}sinc(t)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $u$ and $v$ be Schwartz functions whose Fourier transforms $\hat u$ and $\hat v$ are [bump functions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bump_function) with disjoint support. (To make such $u$ and $v$, start by defining their Fourier transforms, and then set $u$ and $v$ equal to the inverse Fourier transform of the functions you defined.) Then for each $\omega$,
\begin{align*}
\widehat{u\ast v}(\omega) = \hat u(\omega)\cdot\hat v(\omega) = 0.
\end{align*}
Since the Fourier transform is a linear isomorphism of the Schwartz space to itself, $u\ast v = 0$. However, each of $u$ and $v$ are not zero because their respective Fourier transforms are nonzero.

Comment: Sorry, i don't get how this would imply $u\neq0 \wedge v\neq0$

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta: Thanks for asking this clarifying question. I made an addition to my answer—essentially the reason is that we can use again the fact that the Fourier transform is a bijection to understand that $u$ and $v$ are each nonzero. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, at the end i preferred Antonio's answer as it provides the most simple and intuitive example (to my perception)